# Programms running really slow after failed windows update

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, windows-update

My windows started to act really wierd after failed installation (accidentaly rebooted) Windows Malicious Software Removal update.

now Every Microsoft applications runs Ok. But all others take at leas 90 seconds to load.Even Firefox takes 2minutes to load(open) but IE takes 5 seconds to open.. :(

What should I do? I can't see Malicious Software removal update in Control Panel Update list to remove.

Any system registry suggest to check?

Thanks.

Comment: Well since you mentioned the registry, I'd set HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ImpedeNonMSApps back to 0 and see if that fixes it :) (joking! http://www.gpf-comics.com/archive.php?d=20010131)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a System  Restore Point just before the installation of the update. I'd try falling back to that and see what happens.

Failing that, try finding an identical model computer, spec'd the same, and configure it like it was just before the update and see what you get.